# Disable edit popup option for some set of rows of Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a jqgrid. And edit popup option is available for all the rows of the Jqgrid. 
I need to edit popup only for some set of rows of jqgrid, and remaining set of rows should not be editable.
Please suggest me what feature of Jqgrid can help me to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In the releases of jqGrid <= 4.7 the row can not be edited if it has a disabled class. By example in case if you use jQueryUI CSS framework the name of the class is ui-state-disabled.

This mean that if the jqGrid rows having the class ui-state-disabled they can't be edited. This behaviour is available in Guriddo jqGrid and hope it is available in free-jqGrid. Just try.

Comment: Jqgrid version which i am using is 4.8.2.Is this feature available for this version and can anyone pls let me know how to use it

Comment: Please specify which jqGrid - Guriddo jqGrid or  free-jqGrid. The feature is available in a [commercial Guriddo jqGrid 4.8.2](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334).

Comment: it is guriddo 4.8.2 jqgrid

Comment: @MeenakshiRathod you tagged your question with free-jqgrid